# Remote Branch Not Showing in Team Explorer

Tags: git, azure-devops, visual-studio-2017, team-explorer

I am using Azure DevOps as a Git repository, and using VS 2017 with Team Explorer.

When I create a local branch in VS, then push that branch, I do not see that branch when I go to Azure DevOps, then select branches. It only shows master.

If I create a new branch off master in Azure DevOps, then go to Team Explorer and do a fetch or a pull, the new branch never shows up.

The only branch that both me and my colleagues can see is master, but I need to create a new one we can all see in Team Explorer for the test code deployments.

Any ideas how I create a new remote branch that will show in both Azure DevOps and Team Explorer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you push a branch in VS, the message will be something like "Successfully pushed branch mybranch to origin." In this case, "origin" is the name of the remote. If you execute `git remote -v` you should be able to see if the URL of that remote is your Azure DevOps git repo. My guess is that it is not.

Comment: Yup, that was it. Thanks!